# How to filter GLOBAL TEMPORARY tables using Connection.getMetaData().getTables

Tags: java, database, jdbc, oracle11g, database-metadata

I create a global temporary table in Oracle 11g using the following SQL statement.

```
SQL> CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TEST (id int primary key);
```

Now How can I filter out this table using [`Connection.getMetaData().getTables`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) 
.Here I get the `TABLE_TYPE = TABLE` instead of `GLOBAL TEMPORARY` for above `TEST` table

Following is my java code.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class GetGlobalTempTables {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement connStmt = null;
    ResultSet res = null;

    String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
    String user = "testuser";
    String pass = "testpass";
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);
        DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
        res = meta.getTables(null, "TEST_SCHEMA", null, new String[] { "TABLE", "VIEW" });
        while (res.next()) {
            System.out.println(res.getString("TABLE_SCHEM") + ", " + res.getString("TABLE_NAME") + ", "
                    + res.getString("TABLE_TYPE"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (res != null) {
                res.close();
            }
            if (connStmt != null) {
                connStmt.close();
            }
            if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any help will be great appreciated...!

Comment: Check a newer driver version or otherwise file a bug report with Oracle.

Comment: I have downloaded the latest driver from [link] http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Maybe try http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-ucp-122-3110062.html instead, should also work with Oracle 11g (note: I'm not saying it will solve this problem, but sometimes these types of changes are only introduced in newer driver versions)

Comment: I am afraid to say that the latest driver doesn't work with my code.
It throws java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe

Comment: Are you by any chance still using Java 7?

Comment: Yes I am using JDK 1.7.

Comment: Well, that driver I linked to is Java 8 only